# Using special characters in WordPress menu items

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, roots-sage

I'm trying to use the special character "&" in my wordpress menu items. For example having a menu item called "Call & Contact". The issue is the "&" get sign gets converted to "&". I'm not sure if this is a WordPress specific issue or it's my theme (roots / sage 10).

Backend image:[screenshot of wp backend menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlc9k.png)

Frontend image:[screenshot of wp frontend menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF6uC.png)

Comment: &amp; &#38; &#x26;

Answer (score 0):

I"m not 100% sure if that is to solve your problem since there is limited info have been provided but i assumed problem occurs because of your theme and its paginate_links() function.

So what you can try is to add this code to your functions.php file but please do that either in a child theme or with a snippet plugin (easier) because if you copy it somehow wrong your website will crash.

```
    add_filter('paginate_links', 'mmx_pagination_fix');
function mmx_pagination_fix($link) {
    return str_replace('#038;', '&', $link);
}
```

Let me know if it helps. If it doesn't simply delete the code so it doesn't load unnecessarily.

Comment: Hey @Selcuk thanks for the suggestion but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `&amp;` in your menu text (in place of the & symbol) and see if that helps.

Comment: Hey BMartin! Thank you for the response. I put in &amp; instead of & but when I click save it just converts back to the & special character.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows you can use `Windows Key + .` to open emoji popup but you can use `&amp;` for type & character

Comment: Hey Armin! Thank you for the response. I put in &amp; instead of & but when I click save it just converts back to the & special character.